# Multiple file download is not downloading all files in Firefox, anchor click problem

Tags: angular, typescript, firefox, download, anchor

I am trying to download multiple files using typescript in angular 6, From web API service I am getting an array of a blob.

Service to get multiple blobs which I need to download files:

```
 private downloadTest(): void {
    this.downloadService$().subscribe((blobs: Blob[]) => {
        blobs.forEach((blob: Blob, index: number) => {
            FileDownloader.startDownload(blob);
        });
    });
}
```

In a loop I am calling a startDownload method to download the file, below:

```
  export class Downloader {
        public static startDownload(blob: Blob): void {
            blob = new Blob([blob], { type: "type of file" });
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const anchor = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(anchor);
            anchor.download = "fileName";
            anchor.target = "_blank";
            anchor.href = url;        
            anchor.click();
            document.body.removeChild(anchor);
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }    
}
```

The above code is working fine in Chrome but, In Firefox, when anchor click is executed, it breaks the loop and rest of the file is not downloaded,

When I removed anchor.download = "fileName"; it will download the file in firefox too, but open and close new tab. Also, the filename will be Random.

I tried lots of things, but nothing working.

I just wanted to download the file as a different file in a loop, with a specified file name.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Raj Sharma

Comment: one more wired satuation if i use alert("someything") in a startdownLoad it is downloading all files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many approach to work in Firefox, And Finally i put and increase the timeout for every Downlaod, so that one download will not affect the other download.
May be it help someone.

```
private downloadTest(): void {
    this.downloadService$().subscribe((blobs: Blob[]) => {
 let intervalTimeOut = 0;
                blobs.forEach(function (blob, index): void {
                    setTimeout(function (): void {
                        startDownload(blob, fileInfos[index]);
                    }, intervalTimeOut += 100);
                });
    });
}
```